# How to find item in array?

Tags: php, arrays, search

Being new to PHP and its arrays I wonder if there is a better way of doing a simple search like this:

```
$found = "0";
foreach ($myArray as $item) {
    if ($item->id == "Foo") {
      $found = $item->value;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is using an array *of objects*. Important to note.

Comment: So long as `$myArray` is small, let's say max 100, this is good enough. If your data structures get really big you might want to start thinking about sorting (so you can do binary search) or adding indexes.

Comment: how about? [array_search](http://in2.php.net/array_search)

Comment: How about making the data structure better? Use the `ids` as keys, if possible.

Comment: @Log1c - array_search() will work with a simple array of scalars, not an array of objects, not even an array of arrays

Comment: oops, i thought its just an array.

Comment: @MarkBaker my kingdom for callbacks. :P

Comment: There are a large number of ways to do this depending on how you structure your array. If you added your array to your code, we would be able to help you more.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$matchingArray = array_filter($myArray, function($object) {
    return $object->id == 'Foo';
});
```

It will iterate on your array, and call the provided `callback` (second parameter) with each element in your array. The callback needs to return `true`, if the item matches your needs, `false` otherwise.

If you only need the first one:

```
if(count($matchingArray) > 0){
    $firstMatch = $matchingArray[0];
}else{
    // none found.
}
```

Comment: $matchingArray? How does that answer my question? It doesn't look like that code does what my example code does.

Comment: `$matchingArray` contains now all the items from your original array, which have a property called id, and it's value is `'Foo'`.

Comment: I just want the first one, and its value.

Comment: updated. but if you really need only the first match, then use what you originally suggested in your question. it's faster if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
 array_search()
```

or you can simply use:

```
 if(in_array($foo, $bar)
```

where $foo is a value to look for and $bar is an array

Comment: i didnt read that it was an array of objects, but could it not just be the same principle?  if(in_array("foo", $myArray->id)) ?